# Is there a better way to do maps for responsive sites?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I just embedded Google maps on my site and it feels a bit clunky and slow loading when you view it on a mobile phone. Is this how most people do maps on their responsive site?

My map: http://www.ogmda.com/test/location.html

Have any tips or advice on ways to speed up this map loading time and/or anything else I should do?

I'm using BOOTSTRAP.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would reccomend to initially replace the map by a static screenshot of the map. Once the page is *[loaded](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)*, you can use js to load a "live" google map to the spot.

That way the page loads **much** faster (also nice for SEO), and visitors get an instant view of your location, even if the loading of google maps takes some time.

Comment: I think you're on to something. I'll just show a static image that, when clicked, will take the user to the google maps page rather than have them deal with it on my site.

Comment: @user2420614 Sure you want to direct your visitors away from your page? :) If you stick to it, remember to use target="_new".